# Android tabHost accessing specific tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabHost with tree tabs. How can I access a specific tab from the tabHost activity when this tab is not active at the moment.
And a second question to this topic... How can I access the activity of a tab from another tab?

I need this, because I have to update the second tab when something changes on the first tab.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This is it:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
```

Comment: But with this statement the current tab is changed. I would not change the current tab, but I need to access another tab than the current.

Comment: please go through from android developer guide,you can use some thing like tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

    if (arg0.equals("tab1")) {                                Something u needor to call anaother tab host activity by setcurrentTab or else use StartActivity                              }

Comment: and go through getcurrentTab()

Comment: These comments are all not what the person is asking. They are trying to call a function in the activity in the tab from the tabhost activity.